# Change Price Layered navigation Query string structure

Tags: magento-1.9, price, url, layered-navigation

How to change the price layered navigation URL Query string from

```
https://example.com/category.html?price=2%2C10_3%2C10
```

to

```
https://example.com/category.html?price=12-24
```

as I want to make Price slider. so any suggestions ?

Comment: i would suggest using urldecode('https://example.com/category.html?price=2%2C10_3%2C10'), witch translates to: https://example.com/category.html?price=2,10_3,10. But not really sure what you want to achieve....

Comment: well I want to `price=12-24`  ie `Price  $12 to $ 24` and want to remove `?price=2%2C10_3%2C10` or `?price=2,10_3,10` for price attribute in layered navigation

Comment: Have u come up with a solution so far?

Comment: I have used the same `2%2C10_3%2C10` it worked for me, I don't have access to the code, so I can share it, but it will work. I have used Js encodeURI() function to encode url, and now the latest version of Magento, V2 have removed the $ symbol.